# How to highlight errors and warnings on iTerm terminal output?

Tags: iterm, console

I am looking for a solution that would allow me to **use color highlighting to a set of important output messages** inside iTerm terminal application.

Things to highlight:

- application logs file warnings, errors and fatals (apache, nginx, tomcat)
- compiler output
- other similar errors/warnings

[image]

Comment: what exactly is your question here? If it's the question in the title, what do you mean with "optimal"?

Comment: Hmm - let me see if I can help - you have some of the answer in the question. As edited, it's still a bit too much in the category of "•every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?” •your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”

Answer (score 62, accepted):

iTerm supports coloring of console output based on a set of regular expressions. You can set them up in Preferences > Profiles > Advanced > Triggers > Edit.

Here is my current set of regexes:

```
(?i:.*error.*)                     // Yellow on Black
(?i:.*(warning|warn).*)            // Orange on Black
(?i:.*FATAL.*)                     // White on Red
```

[image: iTerm regexes in a profile’s Triggers]

You are welcome to improve it :)

Comment: Any idea what version of iTerm this was introduced? I can't find this option in `Build 0.10`

Comment: I've added this `(\s\sat.*)` To catch any Exception traces such as `at /Users/rootux/.nvm/versions/node/v8.1.2/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:329530:36`

Comment: I have added `( |\[|\(|"|')` to the patter, so the error above would be `(?i:.*( |\[|\(|"|')error( |\]|\)|"|')).*)`. With this the logs like `[246] ./components/src/errors/accessDeniedError.ts 366 bytes {0} [built]` are not highlighted

Comment: Sorry there is a mistake above but not longer able to edit (moderator?). It should be `(?i:.*( |\[|\(|"|')error( |\]|\)|"|').*)`

Comment: Is the text coloring priority is based on the entry we make in triggers? @sorin